# How to open a tab in safari using Selenium in Java

Tags: selenium-webdriver, safari, saucelabs

I've been trying to open tabs in browsers via Selenium and seems to work on all except Safari.

I'm trying the following:

```
public void openNewTab(String url) {
  ((JavascriptExecutor) getWebDriver()).executeScript("window.open('" + url + "','_blank');");
}
```

I've seen some answers in other languages to pass the --legacy argument but not an equivalent for Java.

Any hints?

**Update**

Some related answers include:

- [Request body does not contain required parameter 'handle'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53414873/request-body-does-not-contain-required-parameter-handle)

Here's the error I'm getting when trying the code on the following OS via SauceLabs:

- Mac 10.13
- Mac 10.14
- iPad Pro (12.9 inch) Simulator

  org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: Request body does not contain required parameter 'handle'.
  Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:13:22.693Z'
  System info: host: 'itako4501.prod.miso', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:ca0:e26a:55bf:fecd%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14', java.version: '9.0.4'
  Driver info: driver.version: unknown
  Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
      at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
      at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.reconstructValue(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:40)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:80)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AbstractHttpResponseCodec.decode(AbstractHttpResponseCodec.java:44)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
      at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver$RemoteTargetLocator.window(RemoteWebDriver.java:903)

  Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: Request body does not contain required parameter 'handle'.
  Build info: version: '3.14.0', revision: 'aacccce0', time: '2018-08-02T20:13:22.693Z'
  System info: host: 'itako4501.prod.miso', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:ca0:e26a:55bf:fecd%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14', java.version: '9.0.4'
  Driver info: driver.version: unknown
  Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
  System info: host: 'x-r', ip: 'fe80:0:0:0:4ac:2f6c:527b:c271%en0', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.14.6', java.version: '11.0.3'
  Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Answer (score 1):

This will open a new tab. tried on MacOs Mojave safari Version 12.1.2 (14607.3.9)

```
driver.get("http://google.com");
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.open('http://cnn.com','_blank');");
```

Comment: Hmm, seems to work as I have it locally as well. Maybe a Saucelabs issue?

Comment: Yes, is not working in Saucelabs. Thats's where the error above comes from. Works fine locally.

Comment: Same on Safari 13