# How to build/launch safari 12 with selenium 4-alpha Webdriver using javascript

Tags: selenium, safari, webdriver

I had previously asked [Session not created Selenium/webdriver when using Safari 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52432636/session-not-created-selenium-webdriver-when-using-safari-12)

I've added the selenium-server-4.0.0-alpha-1.jar but I still get the same error

```
browserUnderTest = new webdriver.Builder()
.usingServer( new safari.ServiceBuilder().addArguments('--legacy').build().start())
.forBrowser('safari')
.build();
```

Results in

```
SessionNotCreatedError: Request body does not contain required parameter 'capabilities'.
    at Object.throwDecodedError (/Users/learnincurv/Desktop/MyTestFramework/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:514:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (/Users/learnincurv/Desktop/MyTestFramework/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:519:13)
    at /Users/learnincurv/Desktop/MyTestFramework/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:85:5)
From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
    at Function.createSession (/Users/learnincurv/Desktop/MyTestFramework/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:769:24)
    at createDriver (/Users/learnincurv/Desktop/MyTestFramework/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:170:33)
    at Builder.build (/Users/learnincurv/Desktop/MyTestFramework/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:635:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/learnincurv/Desktop/MyTestFramework/OUR_autotest.js:353:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:643:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:556:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:839:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
  name: 'SessionNotCreatedError',
  remoteStacktrace: ''
}
```

I've not seen any evidence of anyone doing this successfully, and I am hoping someone can point how to get this to run without selenium-grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just re-discovered the somewhat obvious workaround which is to start selenium separately in an other terminal.

```
async function f() {
   startSelenium('open -a Terminal.app startSeleniumForSafari.sh');

   driver = new webdriver.Builder() 
   .forBrowser('safari')
   .usingServer('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub')
   .build();
}

f();
```

The Shell script merely is:

```
echo "Starting Selenium"
java -jar selenium-server-4.0.0-alpha-1.jar -port 4444
echo "Selenium Started"
```